# Typed Dataset connection timeout with oracle client

Tags: c#, oracle10g, strongly-typed-dataset

I am using .net 4.0 with typed dataset to connect to oracle database. When using the development server, it all runs fine. But when moving to staging environment, the dataset always getting connection timeout. Am not able to get the issue behind this.

If I remove the dataset and use direct query using OracleCommand, it works fine, problem is with the typed datase, and at present dont have the time to convert all datasets to DAL layer as it has more than 150-200 commands being used.